# Get the next decade after a given value

Tags: javascript

What's the best way to get the next decade after a given value in Javascript. So for example:

For 9 it would be 10^1 
For 200 it would be 10^3 
For 1001 it would be 10^4

I also need the algorithm to work with negative numbers:

For -9 it would be -10^1 
For 200 it would be -10^3 
For 1001 it would be -10^4

Maybe I've misused the term decade. What I mean is the next whole number that's raised as a power to base 10. So for 9, that's 10^1. For 200, that's 10^3 as 10^2 is less than 200...

Comment: What do you mean by "decade"?

Comment: I mean the next whole number raised to the power of base 10 - sorry that wasn't clear

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the logarithm of 10 and add one to the integer value for the power with 10. You may need to save the sign in advance.

```js
console.log([9, 200, 1001, -9].map(v => (v >= 0 || -1) * Math.pow(10, 1 + Math.floor(Math.log10(Math.abs(v))))));
```

Comment: That's very nice!

Answer (score 2):

You can get the `ceil` of the `log` in the base of 10 to find the power of 10 you need:

```js
function getDecade(number) {
  return (number > 0) ? Math.pow(10, Math.ceil(Math.log10(number))) :
                        -1 * Math.pow(10, Math.ceil(Math.log10(number * -1)));
}

console.log(getDecade(9));
console.log(getDecade(200));
console.log(getDecade(1001));
console.log(getDecade(-9));
console.log(getDecade(-200));
console.log(getDecade(-1001));
```

Comment: @Mark Made a fix that makes it work for negatives too now :)

Comment: Thanks:) Have to give answer to Nina though since its slightly shorter